# How do I share files wtih a chatter group automatically via a trigger?

Tags: trigger, chatter, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

When I upload a file via the chatter feed I want that the file is shared with a particular group in my org with contributor status. I think it must be a trigger on the `ContentDocumentLink` and a `after insert` trigger but how do I change the sharing settings of the given file?

**Edit** Here is my code:

```
trigger publishFileToGroup on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {

    List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroup = [SELECT Id FROMCollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Apex Trigger Group'];  
    List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

    ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink(

    LinkedEntityId = chattergroup[0].Id, ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id, shareType = 'C');

    insert cdl;
}
```

Which creates this error message:

> Apex trigger publishFileToGroup caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: publishFileToGroup: execution of
>   AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row
>   0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   publishFileToGroup: execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row
>   0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Document with ID:
>   06958000000Aejh is already linked with the entity with ID:
>   0F9580000005tul: Linked Entity ID: [LinkedEntityId]

Comment: Can share your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I'm pretty certain you're going to want to be sharing ContentDocumentVersion, NOT ContentDocumentLink to the ContentDocument.